# Error when skipping column in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, axis

I'm using gnuplot to plot some simple data. But in some dataset I need to skip one or more columns.

my data files look like this:

```
#locus_2
5   Bet01_230   0.00057
10  Bet01_230   0.00007
15  Bet01_230   0.00024
20  Bet01_230   0.00312
25  Bet01_230   0.00087
30  Bet01_230   0.00264
```

the datafiles names are stored in "fig2_filenames.txt"

and I'm using this code to (try to) plot the data:

```
clear
set autoscale
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 1 pt 3 linecolor rgb "blue"
set title "Impact of allele frequency and sample size \n on the accuracy of mean sample allele frequency"
set xlabel "sample size"
set ylabel "mean difference from real frequence"
set ytic 0.1
set key off
set term png
filenames = "fig2_filenames.txt"
plot for [i=1:69] 'fig2.dat.out'.i using 1:3 title '', for [i=1:69] 'fig2.dat.out'.i w lines ls 1 title ''
```

But the I get this error message:

> "plot_fig2", line 11: warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>9e+02)

So, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in `...(some format code here)...`; you probably have a very large data range and very small tic spacing.

Comment: Thank you. I've now put the whole code (is not that much).
Indeed I have 69 dataset files do plot in the same graph each one with about 19 lines i the format I previously discribed.

Can't I plot that?

Comment: I suspect it is not the number of files that is the problem, but the data in the 3rd column is probably very large (>90) which leads to the error you get. It seems gnuplot may not support drawing more than 900 tics per axis, at least for whichever terminal you are using. Try removing the line `set ytic 0.1` and see if it plots properly.

Comment: Thats it! :)
Thank you very much for your help.
It is working fine now.

Comment: @andyras Could you provide this as an answer? Thanks.